# Android Assistant on Lollipop

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, google-assistant

Is it possible to get Google Assistant on Android Lollipop smartphone?
I wouldn't prefer to root my phone.

Edit(2 March 2017): Today, as I woke up Assistant suddenly appeared in my app drawer.

[image: Assistant in App Drawer]

[image: Getting familiar with Assistant]

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/google-assistant-tablets-lollipop/ just wait

Comment: @beeshyams Google seems to be a bit dated on this aspect

Comment: @AnuragThakur I had myself live-streamed the event in India where Google declared this. But, the problem is that there has been no further news or updates for over 2 months.

Comment: @AdityaPratapSingh well, we can just hope for the best.

Comment: Is this for a phone or tablet? You weren't specific about that in your question

Comment: @ABochur It is a phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, according to the [Google's blog](https://www.blog.google/products/assistant/google-assistant-coming-to-tablets-and-more-android-phones/), the assistant should definitely work on Android 5.0, for those running their phones in English:

> The Google Assistant on Android 5.0 Lollipop has started to roll out
>   to users with the language set to English in the U.S., UK, India,
>   Australia, Canada and Singapore, as well as in Spanish in the U.S.,
>   Mexico and Spain. It’s also rolling out to users in Italy, Japan,
>   Germany, Brazil and Korea. Once you get the update and opt-in, you’ll
>   see an Assistant app icon in your “All apps” list. ([Source](https://www.blog.google/products/assistant/google-assistant-coming-to-tablets-and-more-android-phones/))

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/2Df8frl9su4QDSjm2   As you can see in the image, I have Android 5.1.1 and the Phone's lang is English. Moreover, I live in India, which comes in the list of countries expected to get the update

Comment: And what happens when you try downloading the [assistant app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.googleassistant)?

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/WW6hW6RyPQzSUvJm1

Comment: @AdityaPratapSingh real strange! That's all I can say...

Comment: Is there any way to 'sideload' Assistant?

Comment: Try installing the [APK](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-assistant/). no guarantee that it's going to work. Won't hurt to try though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73516/discussion-between-aditya-pratap-singh-and-a-bochur).

Comment: I got it finally 